# Dinner Reservations

Tags: probability

Experience shows that $20\%$ of the people reserving tables at a certain restaurant never show up. If the restaurant has 50 tables and takes $52$ reservations, then what is the probability that it will be able to accommodate everyone?

My understanding: If the reservation is $52,$ and $20\%$ people don't show up, would not the probability of accommodating every one be $1$?

Comment: No. There is a $20$% probability that a given person won't show up for his or her reservation but that doesn't mean that on any given day, $20$% of the tables are unoccupied. What you want to calculate is the probability that $50$ or fewer will show up given that the probability that a person shows up is 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a table that has been reserved will be taken by a party who reserved it is $80\%$, the probability that the restaurant accommodates everyone is

$$1 - \Pr[52\ \ \mbox{parties show up}]  - \Pr[51\ \mbox{parties show up}],$$

where probability that $k$ out of $52$ parties show up is

$$\Pr[k\ \mbox{parties show up}] = \binom{52}{k}0.8^{k}(1-0.8)^{52-k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In a statement like "$20\%$ of people don't show up", you're not talking about a portion of *every group of people*. You're talking about the proportion of *people in general*. For example, when a fair coin is flipped, it comes up heads $50\%$ of the time - but that doesn't mean that *every* time I flip my coin twice it'll come up one heads and one tails! It just means that if I were to flip my coin *over and over again*, on average it would come up heads half the time.

In your situation, the "$20\%$" fact at the beginning tells you not that exactly $0.2 \cdot 52 = 10.4$ people will fail to show up (what would that even mean? Someone comes in but leaves an arm and a leg at home?) but instead that *each person* has a $20\%$ chance of not showing up.

The restaurant will have enough space only if at least two people don't show up. That's the same as saying they *won't* have enough space if only only one or zero people don't show up. The probability of zero people not showing up is $0.8^{52} \approx 0.0009\%$, because every single one of the $52$ people would have to hit the $80\%$ chance of showing up. The probability of exactly one person not showing up is $52 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.8^{51} \approx 0.012\%$. The probability of *either one* of those happening is $0.0009\% + 0.012\% \approx 0.013\%$. So the probability of *neither one* happening - in other words, the probability that the restaurant will have enough space - is $100\% - 0.013\% = 99.987\%$.

Answer (score 1):

50 tables can accommodate 50 men. But they have taken 52 reservations.

The restaurant will be able to accommodate everyone, if 50 men or fewer men show up.
Everyone gets a seat when $(X \leq 50)$.
To find this, we use the complement rule.
$1 -$ [Find the chance, Too many men show up with $X = 51$ OR $X = 52$]

Given : 20% of people don't show up. Then,  Success : Men who show up : $p = 80  $% and Failure : Men who didn't show up : $(1-p) = 1 - 80/100 = 20/100$

$\Pr(X \leq 50) = 1 - \Pr(X > 50) = 1 - \sum_{k = 51}^{52} \binom{52}{k}(0.8)^k(0.2)^{52 - k} = 1-[P(X = 51) + P(X = 52)]= 1- [\binom{52}{51}(0.8)^{51}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 51} + \binom{52}{52}(0.8)^{52}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 52} ]$